# SortedList not sorting on key - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sortedlist, icomparer

I have a the need for key value pair that I wish to sort so I decided to use a SortedList instead of a HashTable.

I am adding the data in the order below to my SortedList which is the order I need it in

```
     Key          | Value
     --------------------------------
 1   "700-800"    | List(Of Object)
 2   "900-1000"   | List(Of Object)
 3   "1100-1200"  | List(Of Object)
 4   "1700-1800"  | List(Of Object)
 5   "1900-2000"  | List(Of Object)
```

The key is a string and the value is a List of objects.  The key is representing a time slot that has been concatenated from two integer values and delimited by "-".  "700" as a string was 0700 initially an integer.

e.g.

```
Dim key As String = slotTimeStart.ToString() & "-" & slotTimeEnd.ToString()
```

But once these key value pairs are added to the SortedList they appear in the order

```
 3   "1100-1200"  | List(Of Object)
 4   "1700-1800"  | List(Of Object)
 5   "1900-2000"  | List(Of Object)
 1   "700-800"    | List(Of Object)
 2   "900-1000"   | List(Of Object)
```

Unfortunately I recieve the times slots as two integer values which cannot be changed.

Is there any way to force a sort on a SortedList? or is this problem because of the way I am storing my key? Is there a better way to store it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a [`SortedList(Of String, List(Of Object))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) but pass in an [`IComparer(Of String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) to the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132323.aspx), where the implementation will compare the keys according to the ordering you want.

You'll have to implement that yourself, but it shouldn't be too hard - just split the string by '-', parse both sides with `Int32.Parse` and react accordingly. You may even not need to worry about the part after the '-', if your key ranges are non-overlapping.

EDIT: Here's a demo. It only prints out the keys, but that's enough to show they're sorted as you want them.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new SortedList<string, int>(new RangeComparer());
        list.Add("900-1000", 10);
        list.Add("1100-1200", 20);
        list.Add("700-800", 30);
        list.Add("1700-18000", 40);
        list.Add("1900-2000", 50);

        foreach (var entry in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.Key);
        }
    }
}

public class RangeComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private static int ParseStartOfRange(string range)
    {
        int hyphenIndex = range.IndexOf('-');
        // Normally do some error checking in case hyphenIndex==-1
        string firstPart = range.Substring(0, hyphenIndex);
        return int.Parse(firstPart);
    }

    public int Compare(string first, string second)
    {
        // In real code you would probably add nullity checks
        int firstStart = ParseStartOfRange(first);
        int secondStart = ParseStartOfRange(second);
        return firstStart.CompareTo(secondStart);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon

Are you meaning that when i am adding the key as specified in the post above that i do the following when adding it to the SortedList

sortedlist.Add(key.ToString(New Comparer(implemtation here), List(Of Object))

As i have never used IComparer could you please provide an example?

Comment: No - you supply the IComparer(T) when you create the SortedList. Follow the link I supplied for the word "constructor" :) I can't provide an example right now as I need to cook some dinner - and my VB is horrible. Would you be able to follow a C# example?

Comment: Hey Jon, didn't realise there was links I am still new to the layout of stack overflow :) yes that would be great I am a c# programmer by trade just at a company that needs vb.net

Comment: Thanks Jon, will try this out tomorrow, now i must sleep

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're sorting it alphabetically instead of numerically.  You would have to make your key numeric to get the sort order you're looking for.

Comment: Nope, SortedList allows custom sort orders fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

Times that are less than 4 digits long need to be prefixed with a zero ('0') to make them the same length as the ones with 4 digits. That way, the standard comparer will compare char 1 of string 1 which will now be a 0 to char 1 of string 2 which will be a 1, and string 1 will come out first.

Answer (score -1):

could the keys be decimal and look like

```
7.08
9.1
11.12
17.18
19.20
```

and convert and format to string as needed.

```
    Dim sl As New SortedList(Of Decimal, Object)
    'sample data
    For x As Integer = 7 To 20 Step 2
        sl.Add(CDec(x + ((x + 1) / 100)), New Object)
    Next

    Dim aKey As Decimal
    Dim slotStart As DateTime = #1:00:00 PM#
    Dim slotEnd As DateTime = #2:00:00 PM#

    aKey = CDec(slotStart.Hour + (slotEnd.Hour / 100))
    sl.Item(aKey) = New Object
```